# Proof of the power rule for logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the proof for the power rule for logarithms? And are there different ways to prove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> $$\log_a(M^p)=p\log_a(M)$$

Proof : Let $t=\log_a(M)$. Then, by definition, we have $a^t=M$. So, we have
$$M^p=(a^t)^p=a^{pt}.$$
Hence, we have
$$\log_a(M^p)=\log_a(a^{pt})=pt=p\log_a(M).$$

Comment: Hello, I have a doubt: how did you go from $\log_{a}a^{pt}$ to $pt$ without using the identity itself?

Comment: @Gtexx Because $\log_a(a^x)$ is $x$, by the definition of $\log_a$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to show the identity.  Define the natural logarithm as

$$\log x=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$$

for $x>0$.  Then, we have

$$\log x^n=\int_1^{x^n} \frac{dt}{t}=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{x^{k-1}}^{x^k}\frac{dt}{t} \tag 1$$

Now substituting $t=x^{k-1}u$ in $(1)$ reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\log x^n&=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{1}^{x}\frac{du}{u}\\\\
&=n\log x
\end{align}$$

as was  to be shown!

Comment: Can you elaborate on that substitution I am a bit confused.

Comment: @integratethis It's a standard linear substitution.  There isn't any way to elaborate.  What is the point of confusion?

Answer (score 2):

$$e^{a \cdot \ln(x)}=\left( e^{\ln(x)} \right)^a=x^a$$

$$e^{a \cdot \ln(x)}=x^a$$

The logarithm of the left part can be done easily using the definition.

$$\ln \left( e^{a \cdot \ln(x)} \right)=a \cdot \ln(x)$$

Thus,

$$\ln(x^a)=a\cdot \ln(x)$$

(Posted on mobile)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you define the logarithm function. If you define it as the inverse function of the exponential function, then this isn't hard to prove.

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and let $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

We want to show that $\ln(x^a)=a\ln(x)$. So first let $y=\ln(x^a)$. What is $\exp(y)=e^y$? Then calculate $e^{a\ln(x)}$. Do you find the same result?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

If you define $$\ln x =\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$$ you can make an integration by substitution to prove the identity you mention.

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

$$\log_a(x^n)=n\log_a(x)$$

Proof : Let $λ=\log_a(x)$, thus $a^λ=x$

$$\log_a(x^n)=k$$ Hence we have $a^k = x^n$

Using $a^λ=x$, we have $a^k = a^{λn}$

$$a^k = a^{λn} \implies k = λn \implies k = n\log_a(x)$$
$$\therefore k = n\log_a(x) \implies \log_a(x^n) = n\log_a(x)$$

Comment: Your answer is basically the accepted one.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yeah its similar but not quite same, as I was not satisfied with the accepted one. You could see my comment on the accepted one to understand the rationale for the answer.