# The third law of logarithm (Power Property) proof

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, logarithms

I was asked to prove the third law of logarithm where

$\log A^y = y · \log A$

My "proof" is that:

$\log A^y = y · \log A$

If $\log A^y = \log 10^{(\log A)·y}$

That means that

$\log 10^{(\log A)·y} = y · \log A$

$\log 10$ cancels out leaving $\log A · y = y · \log A$

I am by no means an expert at maths and proofs thus I wonder if my "proof" is correct. I have seen two other ways of proving this law but I am unsure of whether this one is right too.

Comment: Hi Emily. It is unclear to me what you are doing. First I wonder, what kind of number is $y$? If you only care about positive integers $y$, the proof can be easier. Otherwise, you might check this out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340616

Comment: Hi @311411 . Excuse me for being unclear, this field of mathematics is new to me. I think $y$ is considered to be a positive integer. The question does not specify. Also, thank you for the link

Comment: That's what I thought, alright. Let's start modestly, and choose $y = 2$. Also, I will write \log, more standard way. So do you agree we want to prove $\log (A^2)\,=\,2\log(A)$?

Comment: by the way, I am achieving the math formatting by enclosing \log (A^2)\,=\,2\log(A) inside dollar signs.

Comment: Thanks, yes I agree.

Comment: Also should I use the format that you proposed or just enclose an expression using dollar signs?

Comment: okay, so you know that $\log(AB)\,=\,\log(A)+\log(B)$. If $A=B$, then we get $\log(AA)\,=\,\log(A)+\log(A)=2\log(A)$. Can you now show it for $y=3$?

Comment: Oh yes! If y = 3 then A must be multiplied with itself 3 times so we get that: $log(AAA) = log(A) + log(A) + log(A) = 3log(A)$. We could generalise this so $log(A^y) = log(y) + log(y) + log(y) + ... + log(y) = ylog(A)$ A must be multiplied with itself y times which we could write as log(A) + log(A) y times until we achieve our desired result.

Comment: Good, you see the pattern. Now, to really do it for all integers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,.. *forever* you need the principle of Induction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction

Comment: Hi Emily, the basic idea of this proof works.  However it's a bit hard to follow and the order of the logic is unclear. You can re-arrange things to make more clear.  It's easiest to understand when you write is as a series of re-writes: $\log A^y =  \log\left( (10^{\log A})^y)\right) = \ldots = y \log A$ (you fill in the $\ldots$ and justify each step.)

Comment: Hi Jair. What I tried to show above in my post was that by using the expression $x = 10^{(logx)}$ I could substitute $A$ for $10^{(logA)}$. I don't know if it is right but I agree with you!

Comment: @Emily Yup $x = 10^{\log x}$ is true for any $x > 0$ so it is fine to substitute $A$ for $10^{\log A}$. Cheers

Comment: @JairTaylor So it's right? Thank you and 311411  very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember also that $A^y$ means the $y$th product if $A$ with itself, so

$$\ln A^y  = \ln(A \times A \times A \ldots \times A)$$

Where the number of $A$s in the product in the last step is $y$. Then by properties of logs

$$\ln(AB) = \ln A + \ln B$$

One has $y$ copies of $\ln A$ or $y \ln A$.